# Logon windows in other room

Tags: windows

What I want is maybe simple for you guys but I would love to be able to do this in my home.

We have 4 notebooks: mine, my netbook, my wife's notebook and my daughter's notebook. All of these systems are using windows 10 home edition and are on the same network either wired or wireless and on 24 hours a day. What I would like to do is for my to login to the windows account on my own notebook, but them via my wife's notebook and vice versa. I would then also like to have access to my files and therefore hard drive on my notebook.

It seems like something that should be possible very easily, but I have no clue where to start. Is there something I can do in my windows settings, or is there a special piece of software I could use? what I don't want is to use remote desktop and get the screen in screen experience, I want the feel and look as if it was my own notebook I was working on.

In advance thank you all for answering and helping!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to synchronize all your files and [settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/861aa21c-cf7a-48e0-b3dc-54c0b17b3cfa/about-sync-settings-on-windows-10-devices) to the cloud (with windows 10 evident solution is onedrive) and create user account for all of you on all the laptops.

Comment: There a limitation to what Windows 10 settings will synchronize though